# passing props on react context with cloneElement

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use Context in my form, so i have same component for edit and create form. The only difference edit form will have the pre-filled values.

I am adding a sample snippet of the workflow, the problem is here i am getting the props as empty object but i passing the context value on the clone element.

**App.js**

```
<Container {...props}>
  <Fragment>
    <Form />
    <div>
      Latest Details
    </div>
  </Fragment>
</Container>
```

**Container.js**

```
const Container = (props) => {
  const ContainerContext = createContext({ ...defaultState, ...props });
  return (
    <ContainerContext.Provider value={{ ...defaultState, ...props }}>
      <ContainerContext.Consumer>
        {(value) => {
          return React.Children.map(props.children, (child) => {
            return React.cloneElement(child, { ...props, ...value });
          });
        }}
      </ContainerContext.Consumer>
    </ContainerContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

**Form.js**

```
const Form = (props) => {
  console.log(props) // getting empty object
  return 'form'
}
```

Any help is appreciated

**Update**

**App.js**

```
<Container {...props}>
  <Fragment>
    <TopContainer>
      <TopData />
    </TopContainer>
    <MiddleContainer>
      <Form />
    </MiddleContainer>
    <LowContainer>
      <LowData />
    </LowContainer>
  </Fragment>
</Container>;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Container` direct `children` is `React.Fragment` and not your `Form`, so you passing `props` to `React.Fragment` element.

To check it, just log the `props.children` in `Container` component.

```
// Remove React.Fragment
<Container {...props}>
  <Form />
</Container>
```

Comment: If i remove the fragment, the form is repeating multiple times

Comment: i have updated the App.js in the question, i have multiple level, so how can i easily get the props everywhere. I hope you got the idea by seeing the hierarchy with a better example. I tried removing the Fragment but its repeating

Comment: When there is a single component it's coming, i have updated the App.js structure in the question, if it was single i could use cloneElement directly since i had multiple elements using React.Chidlren.map. So is there a way to solve this ?

Comment: You asked a question, I answered, and then you edit your question to a new one

Comment: Just write a recursion function with `Children.map`

Comment: function recursiveMap(children, fn) {
    return React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
      if (!React.isValidElement(child)) {
        return child;
      }

      if (child.props.children) {
        child = React.cloneElement(child, {
          children: recursiveMap(child.props.children, fn),
        });
      }

      return fn(child);
    });
  } 

<ContainerContext.Consumer>{() => recursiveMap()}</ContainerContext.Consumer>

Comment: confused how to pass the values gets from the context, i have added this way, can you correct me on what i am doing here

Comment: <Container.Consumer>
        {(value) => recursiveCloneChildren(props.children, value)}
   </Container.Consumer>

 function recursiveCloneChildren(children, value) {
    return React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
      var childProps = {};
      if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
        childProps = { ...value };
      }
      childProps.children = recursiveCloneChildren(child.props.children);
      return React.cloneElement(child, childProps);
    });
  }

Comment: I have tried this way, the props are not getting and when i debug one per after its showing as undefined.

Comment: @ Dennis, thanks for the info of recursion, i was able to see the child components with the props. Added  the code also, If any improvements needs to do, kindly let me know

Comment: Hi @Dennis Vash, I had one doubt regarding on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70063149/event-timeline-with-animation. If you can help me on this it will be really helpful, many thanks  

Answer (score 0):

As Denish suggested i have tried this way. And this way i was able to solve it.

```
function recursiveCloneChildren(children, value) {
    return React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
      var childProps = {};
      if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
        childProps = {
          ...value,
        };
      }
      childProps.children = recursiveCloneChildren(
        child.props.children,
        childProps
      );
      return React.cloneElement(child, childProps);
    });
  }


 <ContainerContext.Consumer>
        {(value) => recursiveCloneChildren(props.children, value)}
 </ContainerContext.Consumer>
```