# Event timeline with animation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

What i am trying to build is a vertical timeline component with some animation. The animation which am trying is that it starts from the first circle, whichever item has status true the vertical line will draw from top to bottom meanwhile whichever steps gets completed will change from round circle to completed checkmark when the line crosses it.

How can I achieve the above animation on this, I have tried so far but didn't know how to achieve the above.

What am i trying to achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoUgm.jpg)

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-wave-1bjqv)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified your sandbox to make it work:
https://codesandbox.io/s/animable-timeline-reactjs-tiofz

1. For animation I used following CSS:

   ```css
   div {
     height: 200px;
     width: 10px;
   }

   .green-progress {
     background: linear-gradient(0, #00a36c, #00a36c) no-repeat, #ccc;
     background-size: 100% 0;
     animation: progressAnim 3s linear infinite forwards;
   }

   @keyframes progressAnim {
     0% {
       background-size: 100% 0;
     }
     100% {
       background-size: 100% 100%;
     }
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="green-progress"></div>
   ```

   To animate actual time line we'll remove vertical bar from first entry and there will be only checked circle. From second entry onwards we'll have a vertical bar and checked circle. To make them consistent they've been shifted upwards. To show progress, the bar will fill and then circle will be checked.
2. Converted `App` to stateful component so that we can maintain animation states.
   In constructor, for each entry added `id`, `startAnim`, and `checked` state. Here, we'll set `startAnim` flag to start animation on corresponding TimelineConnector. and `checked` is used to control checkmarking the circle.
3. In `TimelineConnector` set class to green-progress if `this.props.startAnim` is true. Also added `onAnimationEnd` handler as `{() => this.props.onAnimDone(this.props.id)}`. This tells App component that animation is done on this component with `id`.
4. In `TimelineDot` used `props.event.checked` to set the checked status.
5. In App added a lifecycle hook `componentDidMount` which will get called when all components gets added to actual DOM. In the hook you checkmark the first circle and start animation on first TimelineConnector.
6. When TimelineConnector is done with the animation, it calls `startNextAnim` in the App. In the method you first complete the checkmark on last entry. And start next animation if the entry has `status:true`.

We could've added delays to each animation and ran them at once. But parent controlling each component and each component notifying when animation is done makes it more flexible to update the code. You can have different animations for each entry, based on their state.
We can use react-spring animation library but things will get complicated. CSS animation is the simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info, i will go through this and will update if in case anything is there, thanks for the help and info :)

Comment: @ onkar, any help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70157795/setting-the-text-width-on-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```css
/* timeline css */
@keyframes fill-color {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes fill-color1 {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 50%;
  }
}
@keyframes scaleup {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    color: rgba(black, 0.4);
  }
  100% {
    color: rgba(black, 1);
  }
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.timeline {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 32px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.details {
  margin-left: 48px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  min-height: 85px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.list,
.list-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.list-content::before,
.list-content::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.2s all linear;
  width: 0.714rem;
  height: 0.714rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
  margin-left: 0.35rem;
  margin-top: rem(-8px);
}

.list-content::after {
  z-index: 2;
}
.list {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.list.active .list-content:before {
  transform: scale(0);
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/White_check.svg/2048px-White_check.svg.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 9px 7px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: -8px;
  animation: scaleup 0.4s forwards;
}
.list:before,
.list:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.2s all linear;
  width: 0.214rem;
  margin-left: 0.6rem;
}
.list:before {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  height: 100%;
}
.list:after {
  background: red;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.list:before {
  top: -50%;
}
.list.active:after {
  top: 0;
  animation: fill-color 0.4s forwards;
}
.list:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
.list:last-child.active:after {
  display: block;
  bottom: 50%;
  animation: fill-color1 0.4s forwards;
}
.list:last-child .details {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.list:first-child:before {
  display: none;
}
.list:first-child.active:after {
  animation: fill-color1 0.4s forwards;
  top: 50%;
}
.list:first-child.active:after {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.list:first-child.active .list-content:before {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.list:nth-child(2).active:after {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.list:nth-child(2).active .list-content:before {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.list:nth-child(3).active:after {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
.list:nth-child(3).active .list-content:before {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.list:nth-child(4).active:after {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
.list:nth-child(4).active .list-content:before {
  animation-delay: 4.15s;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <ul class="timeline">
        <li class="list active">
            <div class="list-content">
                <div class="details">
                 <h4 class="status-title">Step 1</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list active">
            <div class="list-content">
                <div class="details">
                 <h4 class="status-title">Step 2</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list active">
            <div class="list-content">
                <div class="details">
                 <h4 class="status-title">Step 3</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list active">
            <div class="list-content">
                <div class="details">
                 <h4 class="status-title">Step 4</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

you can also check on [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-euler-zdf1b?file=/src/styles.css)

here I have added `active` class in all `li` elements but if you want to two steps active so apply only first two li (i.e that class is conditional)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to animate a background. Please check the example below

```css
.bg {
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(0, red, red) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 0;
  animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-size: 100% 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Your TimelineConnector could be updated with include of that CSS class.

Comment: Thanks, here i have tried making the line animated but the problem was i don't know how to animate one by one as shown in the gif, since as per the data only three are completed so how should draw the line till the completed steps that's where i am not able to move ahead

Comment: Sure, you could add an additional parameter for an animation as a CSS variable defined from your React script with number of item * timeout, something like that: animation: gradient 15s ease infinite var(--timeout);

Comment: To define CSS variable in a scope of element you could use such method: element.style.setProperty('--timeout', '0.5s');

Comment: sorry may be am newbie to this, if you can help can you share the codesandbox which you were able to solve as like the Gif

Comment: It could be made as a loop through items and a set of different timeouts. Example: https://codepen.io/alekskorovin/pen/ExvJOrz

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-wave-1bjqv how to achieve on this ?

Comment: Can you point me or if you are aware of any kind of react component library which gives of this kind of timeline with animation mentioned in the question

Comment: In terms of your example these edits could help you to start - https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-phoebe-ip749

Comment: Thanks for the help, i have added the changes but still  the problem i am facing is the animation is starting after few seconds and as per the GIF, first should start once it reaches the rounded changes to completed and also a grey line will be present, the animation which we add should be over through that one
I was checking for this kind of component because most of the e-commerce site have it, but not getting the right component library

Comment: @dev I think if you modify this, it might fit your requirements, https://codesandbox.io/embed/brave-kepler-fdbzv?file=/src/App.js:0-1097&codemirror=1

Comment: @Shujath i have referred this also but I don't know how to remove that mutation observer part and implement it.