# Getting the previous value and updating n+1 item

Tags: javascript

I have an array of sequences, what i am trying to achieve is whichever last object **completed** property is true, then the next to next object will have **is_to_happen** as true

**input**

```
const sequences = [
    {
        "title": "Order placed",
        "completed": true
    },
    {
        "title": "To be confirmed",
        "completed": false
    },
    {
        "title": "Approx Thursday product will be shipped",
        "completed": false
    }
]
```

And this is what i want to have as an expected output

```
const output = [
    {
        "title": "Order placed",
        "completed": true,
        "is_to_happen": false
    },
    {
        "title": "To be confirmed",
        "completed": false,
        "is_to_happen": false
    },
    {
        "title": "Approx Thursday product will be shipped",
        "completed": false,
        "is_to_happen": true
    }
]
```

What i have tried so far using array.reduce is not working

```
sequences.reduce((acc,curr) => {
    acc = [...acc, curr]
    if(curr.completed){
     acc = [...acc, {...curr, is_to_happen: true}]
    }
    return acc     
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usea `reduce`, and also keep track of the index of the `completed` item:

```js
const sequences = [
    {
        "title": "Order placed",
        "completed": true
    },
    {
        "title": "To be confirmed",
        "completed": false
    },
    {
        "title": "Approx Thursday product will be shipped",
        "completed": false
    },
    { "title": "One more step", "completed": false }
]

const result = sequences.reduce ( (acc,item, i) => {
  if(item.completed) acc.completedIndex = i;
  acc.items.push( {...item,"is_to_happen": (acc.completedIndex != -1) && (i >= acc.completedIndex+2) } );
  return acc;
},{items:[], completedIndex:-1});

console.log(result.items);
```

Another way to achieve the same is to look backwards 2 elements in the original array for the `completed` flag

```js
const sequences = [
    {
        "title": "Order placed",
        "completed": true
    },
    {
        "title": "To be confirmed",
        "completed": false
    },
    {
        "title": "Approx Thursday product will be shipped",
        "completed": false
    }
]

const result = sequences.map ( (item, i) => {
  return {...item, is_to_happen: !!sequences[i-2]?.completed};
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Just one doubt, if i need to be generic on the above function, assume if the array length increases from 3 to 4, I can see that 4th object having is_to_happen as false. Which is wrong
So how can I achieve this ?

Comment: const sequences = [
    {
        "title": "Order placed",
        "completed": true
    },
    {
        "title": "To be confirmed",
        "completed": false
    },
    {
        "title": "Approx Thursday product will be shipped",
        "completed": false
    },
    {
        "title": "One more step",
        "completed": false
    }
]

const result = sequences.map ( (item, i) => {
  return {...item, is_to_happen: !!sequences[i-2]?.completed};
});

console.log(result);

Comment: sure let me try it and will update thanks :)

Comment: @dev my mistake that should have been `(i >= acc.completedIndex+2) ` - have updated the first example

Comment: Sure thanks that works, will just check few other test cases around it for making generic. Thanks @ Jamiec

Comment: If you are any chance aware of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70063149/event-timeline-with-animation it will be helpful, many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```js
 const todo = [
        {
            "title": "Order placed",
            "completed": true
        },
        {
            "title": "To be confirmed",
            "completed": false
        },
        {
            "title": "Approx Thursday product will be shipped",
            "completed": false
        }
    ]
    
    // find last completed
    var lastCompleted = todo.slice().reverse().find(item => item.completed === true);
    // get the index of the next to the next item.
    var nextToDoIndex = todo.indexOf(lastCompleted) + 2;
    // only change it if it exists.
    if(todo[nextToDoIndex]) todo[nextToDoIndex] = {...todo[nextToDoIndex], is_to_happen: true } 

    console.log(todo)
```

Comment: It will be helpful if it can be generic in this case if the array of sequences gets increased the new object will have is_to_happen as false

Answer (score -1):

```
sequences.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (curr.completed)
    acc = [...acc, { ...curr, is_to_happen: true }]
  else
    acc = [...acc, { ...curr, is_to_happen: false }]
  return acc
}, [])
```

try this.

Comment: Did you try it? It will not give the output the OP required!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).